# I was created one API, get the ID from android and that ID details send to the android

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I hit the API I get the result dynamically those I users previously. Before that I created many API for the android but I never facing problem like this.

Here is the code

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
   echo $empId = $_REQUEST['empId'];
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
   $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   require_once "db.php";
   $query = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `mobileNumber`, `tempMobileNumber`,                                    `email`, `photo`, `supervisorId`, `emergencyMobileNumber`, `emergencyName`,  `relation`, `address`, `designation`, `appId`, `qrCode`, `vendorId`, `siteName`,  `latitude`, `langitude` FROM `tbl_employee` WHERE `appId`= $empId";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
echo $count = $result->num_rows;

if($count > 0) 
{
    $response["empDetails"] = array();
    $row_user = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $emp = array();
    $emp["ID"] = $row_user["id"];
    $emp["appId"] = $row_user["appId"];  
    $emp["name"] = $row_user["name"];
    $emp["mobileNumber"] = $row_user["mobileNumber"];
    $emp["tempMobileNumber"] = $row_user["tempMobileNumber"];
    $emp["email"] = $row_user["email"];

    array_push($response["empDetails"], $emp);
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Attendance Placed Successfully.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    echo "wrong";
}
?>
```

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query); result not getting properly

Comment: comment the line of error reporting than see what error you getting in code

Comment: Can you please share your code for "db.php" as well  ?

Comment: @PrashantKumbhar look the below answers and try with the answers in your code

Answer (score 1):

in the above question your query is wrong and the and also linebreak(;) is missing
 update your query line with this

```
$query = "SELECT * from table_name where your_id='$empId';    // you can add the column name which you want to retrieve.
```

In your code above your this query line is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You just rewrite your query as (replace your existing query with this):

```
 $query = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `mobileNumber`, `tempMobileNumber`, `email`, `photo`,   `supervisorId`, `emergencyMobileNumber`, `emergencyName`,  `relation`, `address`, `designation`, `appId`, 
   `qrCode`, `vendorId`, `siteName`,  `latitude`, `langitude` FROM `tbl_employee` WHERE `appId`= '".$empId."'";
```

I think you have made the mistake in string append syntax. May this will work in your case.

Also check you have connected the database properly